# Very specific c array for a beginner

Tags: c, arrays

I have c code that needs to keep track of a timer(in a MCU), store that timer's value in an array(size 4, "small_array"), and then store small_array 64 times in another array(large_array). I then need to take the value of TIMER, extrapolate it from both arrays, and take the average. Here is some code I tried to write. I'm a beginner and LOVE to code already, but I am trying to get better!

```
#define input1 GP4

int a;
unsigned char b;
int small_element;
int large_element;
int small_array[];
int large_array[];
input1=input2;
TMR0=TIMER;

main()
{
//Initializations go here
small_element=0;
large_element=0;
for(a=0;a<64;a++)
{
    /*when large_array[] receives its first value from small_array[] below, then execute*/  
    for(b=0;b<4;b++)
    {
        if(!input2 && input1)  
        {
            TIMER=0;
            if(!input2 && input1)
            {
                small_array[small_element]<<=1; /*move the previous value of small_element
                over 1 space in small_array[](to make space for the next value in the next line)*/
                small_array[small_element]=TIMER;
            }
        }
    }
    large_array[large_element]<<=1;/*move the previous value of large_element
                over 1 space in large_array[](to make space for the next value in the next line)*/
    large_array[large_element]=small_array[small_element];
}
/*now somehow I need to extract all of the values of TIMER to find the average
from the arrays in my for loops(which should give me 64*4 values(265 values) of TIMER.*/
}
```

Comment: The average of any number (say `n`) repeated `256` times is `n`.

Comment: Also `<<=` is not a "move over" instruction. It's a left (bit-wise) shift.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Will my timer value still be stored in the array sequentially if I don't tell it to physically move with a "bit-shift-like" command? Also, I realize the math behind the average, however, I need to implement that in the code without the gigantic and time consuming division comman. Perhaps a bit-shift-like command of some kind? I really don't know.

Comment: No, you need to change your array index. Not bit shift the values in your array... `<<=1` is the same as `*= 2`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you give me and example how I can change my array index in this case?

Comment: If you didn't understand it five days ago, why did you accept an answer?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch IMO accepting an answer on here as a beginner is like flying a plane as a beginner in the dark. Air traffic control telling you which buttons to press by radio but with no idea how they work or what they do. Mayday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array declaration

```
int small_array[];
int large_array[];
```

is wrong. A size is needed inside `[]` if it is not initialized.

```
int small_array[4];
int large_array[64];
```

Comment: To add some detail for the OP, an initialized array can be of the form `int array[]={4,3,2,1}`. In this case the compiler figures out the size required (counts how many elements there are in the curly brackets) and allocates accordingly.

Comment: Size is needed except when the array is declared with `extern` storage class, or as a zero-length or flexible array member(last member) of a `struct` type.

Comment: Also `C99` supports variable-length array so size of an array doesn't have to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @ajay; I never said it is always compile time constant.

Comment: @haccks, do I not need something like this in order to put arrays inside my other array, and then take the average of TIMER? I took this example off the net:   myArray = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));